# Android How to get Json Parsing from Json String?

Tags: android, json

In my app I am getting Json String response when calling with a URL. the Json String response is like this:

```
jsonFlickrApi({
    "user": {
        "id": "87074969@N08",
        "nsid": "87074969@N08",
        "username": {
            "_content": "polamreddy_subbareddy"
        }
    },
    "stat": "ok"
})
```

From that, I want to get the `id` value through parsing. How would I do that?

Comment: its not a valid json string. just check at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: EDIT: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=json+parsing+android&oq=json+parsing+android)

Comment: You should seriously google first before asking on stack overflow. Search "json parsing android" on http://www.google.com. You will get infinite results and good tutorials. And then if you face a problem then come to SO.

Comment: Your JSON String Not in valid Format.you need to update it to right format.you can check [it here](http://jsonlint.com/) or    [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i got solution from this:

```
thedata = new MyData().GetRequest(url, null, timeout);
Log.i(TAG, "" +thedata);

jObject = new JSONObject(thedata); 

JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject("user");
attributeId = menuObject.getString("id");
Log.i(TAG, "" +attributeId);
```

and initialize the variables:

```
private final int[] timeout={3,10};
private String thedata;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON String is ..

```
       {
         "user":{
         "id":"87074969@N08",
         "nsid":"87074969@N08",
         "username":{
           "_content":"polamreddy_subbareddy"
                   }
      },
         "stat":"ok"
    }
```

Then parse data is this way ..

```
     JSONObject returnResult = jList.getJSONFromUrl();

     JSONObject status = returnResult .getJSONObject(stat);
     JSONObject user = returnResult .getJSONObject(user);

     String id = user.getString(id);
     String nsid = user.getString(nsid);
 JSONObject username = user.getJSONObject(username);
    String contenr = username .getString(content);
```

Try this ..feel free to ask any query